# Moment of sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

I'm stuck at the following problem. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space with $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables defined over it. Then, if $\mathbb{E}[\mid X+Y \mid ^p]<+\infty$ for some $p>0$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[\mid X\mid^p]<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[\mid Y\mid^p]<\infty$.

I really have no intuition about this result. It looks like those results derived from convexity type arguments (for the case $p>1$), which I never really understood all that well. I also tried to break up the first integral into integrals over sets I could manage but also got nowhere. I see that independence is the key here since this is obviously not true in general without this requirement: if $X$ is any non integrable random variable, taking $Y = -X$ would suffice (but of course, they are not independent in this case..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise on Fubini's Theorem. $\int\int |x+y|^{p} dF_X(x)dF_Y(y) <\infty$ and this implies that $\int |x+y|^{p} dF_X(x)<\infty$ for almost all $y$. We can fix a $y$ for which this holds. Now use the inequality $|x|^{p} \leq 2^{p} ({|x+y|^{p}+|y|^{p}})$ to conclude that $\int |x|^{p} dF_X(x) <\infty$, so $E|X|^{p} <\infty$. Similarly,  $E|Y|^{p} <\infty$.

Comment: Why can we express the first integral in the way you did?

Comment: @AndréMuchon That is becasue $P\circ (X,Y)^{-1}=P\circ X^{-1} \times P\circ Y^{-1}$ by independnece.